# Could a 100 solar mass black hole at 0.01c passing just at 123 AU change the direction the sun is moving by 90°?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, black-holes, estimation, solar-system

I asked the person claiming to have created [this video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MVsz.jpg) of such an encounter why this simulation suggests that the sun is moving in a direction that is parallel to the plane of the ecliptic? I'd thought the sun was moving close to perpendicular to the ecliptic.

The response I got was "it wouldn’t be after a black hole tore past."

I found that an odd answer and it raised many more questions about the accuracy of the video, but it first got me wondering if a 100 solar mass black hole at 0.01c passing just at 123 AU could change the direction the sun is moving by 90°?

Comment: All motion is relative. So, what's your reference frame for the motion of the Sun?

Comment: The orbit of the sun around the galactic center. Is that a reference frame that makes sense in the context of this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic I have no object to the edit, but why is Newtonian mechanics preferable to Classical mechanics?

Comment: Classical mechanics sometimes includes relativity while Newtonian mechanics does not. It seems a non-relativistic estimate suffices.

Comment: What has this got to do with black holes? Also, the direction of the solar motion around the galaxy is not parallel or perpendicular to the ecliptic plane.

Comment: What is the direction of solar motion around the galaxy in respect to the ecliptic plane?

Answer (score 5):

A 100 solar mass black hole at 123 AU is 62 million Schwarzschild radii away, and 1% c is not very relativistic either,  so we can clearly safely use a Newtonian approximation here.

If we use a reference frame moving with the sun, which seems to be the case here, then obviously the sun will just start moving in the direction the hole passed. If we instead consider the reference frame following the hole, we see the sun shooting down at 1% c along a line parallel to the hole travel direction (at distance $b$), and then get deflected along a hyperbolic arc to travel away at a different direction, still at 1% c. The change in direction corresponds to the change in speed from zero to moving in the sun reference frame.

The change in velocity direction is $2\tan^{-1}(-GM/b v^2)$ (e.g. [(Reed 2014)](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0143-0807/35/4/045009)). Note that this grows as $b$ decreases (closer encounters) but decreases as $v$ increases (faster encounters). A relativistic flyby is "safer" than a slow flyby.

You get a right turn if $GM/b v^2=1$, or in this case $bv^2\approx 10^{22}$ m$^3$ s$^{−2}$. If we insist on $b=123$ AU then the hole needs to saunter past at just 26.8 km/s. If we insist on 1% c, then $b$ needs to be about 2.12 solar radii - still ample space for the hole, which is less than a thousandth of the size of the sun, but now I would start to worry about tidal interactions causing extra complications.

Answer (score 1):

Universe Sandbox is a (great) mass-market educational entertainment product. There's no reason to suspect that the author has any knowledge of physics.

In the simulation, the black hole passes orthogonally through the plane of the solar system. If you integrate its gravitation from plus to minus infinity, all the parts that aren't parallel to the plane cancel out, so it can only possibly impart a change in velocity on the plane of the solar system. The simulation doesn't show the sun changing course by 90 degrees, *it starts in the rest frame of the sun* and shows the deviation of the sun's course from the sun's rest frame.

I'm on my phone at the moment so I'm not going to do out the integration, but a bit of order of magnitude napkin algebra gets me a change in velocity on the order of about 10m/s for the sun, which is on the order of one part in ten thousand of the $\Delta v$ required to effect a right angle turn in the sun's velocity w/r/t the galactic center.

Comment: Much appreciated. I recognize the simulation doesn't indicate a change in course, but the idea that the direction of the sun's movement in the simulation was parallel to the ecliptic when it is generally closer to perpendicular, made me wonder if the sun's movement could be radically changed with the passing of a black hole.